# <DispatcherServlet name of web.xml>-servlet.xml is necessary

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I just started with spring MVC. I want to configure controllers in separate xml and instead of -servlet.xl file. Is is compulsory to define an xml file with that name or can't I use ContextLoaderLister.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use an xml file with that name so I'd say it's not compulsory at all. You might wish to explain your situation more so that we could potentially determine why it might seem like you have to.

Comment: The case is, I like to configure different components of spring MVC in their respective configuration files instead of a single file [servlet-name]-servlet.xml

Comment: Couldn't you just import the other xml files into one xml file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it compulsory to define an xml file
>   with that name

No it is NOT; name `<DispatcherServlet name of web.xml>-servlet.xml` is just the default value.

You can change the name of the file like this.... ([mvc-showcase/web.xml](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml))

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Comment: Yeah I have done the same(i.e for contextConfigLocation provided values like /WEB-INF/spring*.xml and added a contextLoaderListener). Though application deployed successfully when the first request comes sping throwing FileNotFounException by stating [servlet-name]-servlet.xml